# Getting error while Installing LWR Application

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata, lwr

I am trying to install the az-insurance app, and getting below error -

```
Error LWR_Demo_Marketing1 The value for urlPathPrefix in ExperienceBundle isn't valid. Check the value and try again.
```

I am following the steps mentioned here- https://github.com/trailheadapps/az-insurance. Code exist in LWR_Demo_Marketing1.site-meta.xml is as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<ExperienceBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <label>LWR Demo Marketing</label>
    <type>ChatterNetworkPicasso</type>
    <urlPathPrefix>marketing</urlPathPrefix>
</ExperienceBundle>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to add an `/s` like:

```
<urlPathPrefix>marketing/s</urlPathPrefix>
```

See this ref [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_experiencebundle.htm)

> For authenticated LWR sites created before Winter ’23 and Aura sites, the URL path prefix ends in /s and the part of the path without the /s must match the Network metadata type’s URL. For unauthenticated LWR sites and authenticated LWR sites created after Winter ’23 through Experience Builder or Connect API, this path doesn’t contain /s, and the path can be anything as long as there is no conflict.

Comment: Thank you this is useful. I have added the /s but still having issues. Checking the other things if I miss anything

Comment: Adding /s did not work for me either.